# Using Teamcity properties inside nant script

Tags: teamcity, nant

I'm trying to use a teamcity agent property in my nant scripts. This works perfectly when I run the build using teamcity. However, since there is no way to evaluate the property outside teamcity, the scripts fail when I run nant via commandline. Here is the sample code -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="script" default = "publish"> 
  <target name="publish">
    <echo message="${agent.home.dir}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic in this. Please Help!

Comment: Can you evaluate environment variables in nant?

Comment: Yes. The following would give me the path variable set on the machine.     ${environment::get-variable('path')}

Comment: Then you can define TeamCity environment variables perhaps? Prefix their name with `env.` to define them as environment variables. If you need to access internal TeamCity variables, create an environment variable in TeamCity that references the internal variable and it should work nicely.

Comment: A good exercise is to create a simple command line script that just executes `SET` to dump out all known variables, typically a lot of the variables are present under a different name.

Comment: Nice Idea... But it wouldn't solve my issue since the cmd is used on machines where we don't have teamcity installed. I need a way to evaluate these variables to a default value in case I'm running from cmd.

Comment: What about creating a batch file that sets the default values? I am unfortunately not familiar with nant enough to give you any further advice, but it sounds like this is not a TeamCity issue, it's more that you want a single nant script to evaluate teamcity variables when executed from TeamCity, and something else when otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue when using NAnt with TeamCity as it will work fine running it from TeamCity but if you do the build via command line it will fail because NAnt does not know what those TeamCity variables are.

My Solution was simple. Since the only time my build needed to interact with TeamCity is during a TeamCity invoked build I gave the user the option to turn off that feature if needed to run it from a command line.

Example:

```
<property name="TeamCity.BuildFeatures" value="false" />

<if test="${bool::parse(TeamCity.BuildFeatures)}"  >
 <echo message="Your TeamCity variables like ##teamcity[] are ignored" />
</if>
```

Hope this is useful..

**EDIT Based on Comments:**

```
<property name="agent.home.dir" value="..\TeamCity\BuildAgent" />


  <exec program="msbuild.exe" basedir="${msbuilddir}" commandline="\testProject.csproj">
        <arg value="/property:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86"/> 
        <arg value="/verbosity:diagnostic"/> <arg value="Verbosity=diagnostic;Encoding=UTF-8"/>
     <if test="${property::exists('agent.home.dir')}" > 
        <arg value="/l:JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.MSBuildLogger,${agent.home.dir}\p‌lugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.dll" if="${teamcity}" />
        </if>
```

Comment: Thanks @Geddon! I was also thinking on the similar lines. But the  Nant compiler seems to evaluate all the properties before executing any if blocks. This code fails -

Comment: <exec program="msbuild.exe" basedir="${msbuilddir}" commandline="\testProject.csproj">  
    <arg value="/property:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86"/>      <arg value="/verbosity:diagnostic"/>      <arg value="Verbosity=diagnostic;Encoding=UTF-8"/>      <arg value="/l:JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.MSBuildLogger,${agent.home.dir}\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.dll" if="${teamcity}" />

Comment: In this case you can also check if the property exist, Nant will not cause an issue then. <if test="${property::exists('teamcity')}" > . Will update the answer so that is it clearer. Basically add conditions to any TeamCity Property and maybe use a global property to turn it on or off depending on the build.

Comment: What is this equal to? ${teamcity}, if this is just a property then you are fine. What is it failing on?

Comment: ${teamcity} is just a property that I set when running from teamcity. Default would be false. The problem with this approach is, I'd need to use 2 exec programs. I wanted to do away with that situation, since there are multiple projects and a lot of such calls already.

Comment: What's an example of the teamcity variables you use in your build script? You said it works in TC but not on cmd, right?

Comment: ${agent.home.dir} is the teamcity variable that I'm trying to use. Yes, it works with TC but not with cmd.

Comment: For that property to fail in cmd it has to be something Nant cannot understand. What's the error or what u have that value defined as? If it is just a path, then you can define that in your Nant script (see above). For example, this is a TC variable (##teamcity[]) that NAnt cannot interpret by itself unless you run it inside TC.